# The client wants only w-2, is there a way to route this via LLC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, form-w-2, intellectual-property

I have an LLC registered and operating in USA. I produce content. My client is in DC. I would like to provide services using the content that my LLC owns. The client is not directly buying the content, but wants to hire me on W-2 to provide services using that content. Think of it as if LLC owned a song, and the client wanted me to perform it for money. It's not a song that we produce but the idea's similar.

I want my client's pay to be recognized as a revenue of my LLC for utilization of the content that belongs to LLC, and the expenses to create the content are recognized too. How should I handle this situation?

The content belongs to LLC and the client has no claim to it.

Comment: I think you need to resolve the legal issues of whether this idea protects your content first, as companies usually own the work produced by employees. You are probably not authorized to enter into licensing agreements on behalf of the company, even if it's your own work.

Comment: I'd suspect the answer is "No.  At least without a fairly large investment in lawyer and accountant gymnastics to come up with a way to fit this very square peg into a very round hole.  Which is almost certainly not worth it unless this is a very large deal."  But from a practical standpoint, why on earth would the client want to hire you as a W2 employee, pay unemployment, pay payroll taxes, deal with benefits etc. rather than simply paying an invoice from your LLC?  I'm hard-pressed to see any way that makes the client's life easier which makes me wary that something is being left out.